# How to select latest date record and show other columns in mysql?

Tags: php, sql

I'm using XAMPP MYSQL

I have table and the `Date` Column is String

```
  Date    |  Customer   |   Location   | Cash | Balance |
2015/6/23    LBalance      California    5000    3000
2015/6/25    LBalance      New York      6000    4500
2015/6/25    InHoss Dept.  South Beach   15000   1000
2015/6/20    InHoss Dept.  South Beach   15000   1000
2015/6/17    InHoss Dept.  South Beach   15000   1000
2015/6/22    LBalance      California    5000    4000
2015/6/22    LBalance      New York      6000    6000
2015/6/17    InHoss Dept.  North Beach   18000   1000
```

How to select query the latest date record of each customer with different locations?

Expect result:

```
Date      |  Customer   |    Location   | Cash | Balance |
2015/6/23    LBalance      California    5000    3000
2015/6/25    LBalance      New York      6000    4500
2015/6/25    InHoss Dept.  South Beach   15000   1000
2015/6/17    InHoss Dept.  North Beach   18000   1000
```

this is the closest i've been to: SELECT Customer, Location, Cash, Balance, max(Date) AS "As Of" FROM mytable WHERE Customer = 'LBalance' GROUP BY Customer, Location. Although It's showing the most recent date of a customer but the other column is just showing their first result.

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY` with `MAX`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i guess its a homework

Comment: please show what do you want in real example, what will be expected result

Comment: I want to see only the latest date of each user's result.

Comment: @MonPadi the below answers doesn't answer your questoin ?

Answer (score 0):

select (*) from xampp 
where date = (select max(date) from xampp)

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
with cte (date, Customer, Location, Cash , Balance) as
(
select cast('2015/6/23' as datetime) date, 'LBalance' Customer, 'California' Location, 5000 Cash , 3000 Balance
union all
select cast('2015/6/25' as datetime) date, 'LBalance' Customer, 'New York' Location, 6000 Cash , 4500 Balance
union all
select cast('2015/6/25' as datetime) date, 'InHoss Dept.' Customer, 'South Beach' Location, 15000 Cash , 1000 Balance
union all
select cast('2015/6/20' as datetime) date, 'InHoss Dept.' Customer, 'South Beach' Location, 15000 Cash , 1000 Balance
union all
select cast('2015/6/17' as datetime) date, 'InHoss Dept.' Customer, 'South Beach' Location, 15000 Cash , 1000 Balance
union all
select cast('2015/6/22' as datetime) date, 'LBalance' Customer, 'California' Location, 5000 Cash , 4000 Balance
union all
select cast('2015/6/22' as datetime) date, 'LBalance' Customer, 'New York' Location, 6000 Cash , 6000 Balance
union all
select cast('2015/6/27' as datetime) date, 'InHoss Dept.' Customer, 'North Beach' Location, 18000 Cash , 1000 Balance
)

select m.Date, m.Customer, m.Location, m.Cash, m.Balance 
   from cte m
   where m.Date = (select max(mm.Date) 
                     from cte mm 
                    where mm.customer=m.customer
                      and mm.location = m.location )
```

i have checked in my example everething is ok, please be sure that you are using mysql example

Comment: The OP wants the latest `record`, which I interpret to mean it wants the entire record.

Comment: It's just repeating and showing all dates and records. I just want to show only the above expected result.

Comment: try again i have added location

Comment: Just the same sir

Comment: this is the closest i've been to:    SELECT `Customer`, `Location`, `Cash`, `Balance`, max(`Date`) AS "MostRecentServiceMonth" FROM `mytable` WHERE `Customer` = 'LBalance' GROUP BY `Customer`, `Location`. Although It's showing the most recent date of a customer but the other column is just showing their first result.

Comment: look my answer again, please be sure that you are using mysql example, i have checked it and i have get expected result

Comment: Wait sir. I experience a error in xampp database. All the records are gone. Last time I saw "java failed" something like that. Can you help me out? All the records are gone.

Answer (score 0):

to get latest record you use max() function, as for each customer and location you use group by 
check the bellow:

```
select max(date) , CUSTOMER, LOCATION from table GROUP BY CUSTOMER , LOCATION
```

edit. if the date is varchar(logically wrong) you can do at the below.

```
 select Max(cast(date as Date)) , CUSTOMER, LOCATION from table GROUP BY CUSTOMER , LOCATION
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, you wanted a date to string conversion. Not sure this is needed though, since, max(date) might still work without the conversion.

```
select max(STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%Y/%m/%d')),Customer, location, cash,balance from YourTable group by Customer, Location
```

Happy Coding.. Please confirm what you need. Becomes difficult to keep track of the edits.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this

```
select a.*
from yourtable a JOIN
( select Customer,Location,Max(Date) as Mdate
   from yourtable
   group by Customer,Location) b
on a.Customer=b.Customer and a.Location=b.Location and a.Date=b.Mdate
```